# Finding the most recent records from duplicates

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to get the most recent records from a table where there are duplicates for each row.
Every month a new row for some IDs is getting added to the table, but some other records might not have a new row each month so the data will be like this

```
ID   Date
1    8/30/2022
1    7/30/2022
3    8/30/2022
3    7/30/2022
3    6/30/2022 
4    1/11/2021

The query result should be

ID   Date
1    8/30/2022
3    8/30/2022
4    1/11/2021
```

I tried to use a sub-query, but it is only returning records that actually has the most recent for the whole table not per ID so it is only returning those who has a record in 8/30/2022.

This is my query

```
create table  test as (
select * from table1 inner join
(select EmpID, max(Record_Date) as maxdate
from table1 group by EmpID) ms
on table1.EmpID ms.EmpID and Record_Date=maxdate)
 WITH DATA;
```

Comment: You can use `qualify` here - `select ... from <table> qualify row_number() over (partition by empid order record_date desc) = 1`.

Comment: is that in the sub-query ?

Comment: No, you don't need the subquery, unless I'm misunderstanding your goal.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the subquery example shown other than the missing = in the ON clause, but that would give a syntax error so is likely a typo. There must be some other issue with the "real" query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `NOT EXISTS` operator with correlated subquery as the following:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Date
FROM Table1 T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 D WHERE D.ID=T.ID AND D.Date>T.Date)
```

And of course, if you want to create a new table from this statement the query will be:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS 
  (
    SELECT T.ID, T.Date
    FROM Table1 T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 D WHERE D.ID=T.ID AND D.Date>T.Date)
  ) WITH DATA;
```